# How to update every rows which has a number greater than or equal to the joining table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is an example of the tables I am joining together (note: the tables have the exact same schema but are in different databases, I am trying to combine them):

```
Database 1 Table 

UniqID UniqID2 Number 
100     150     1
100     151     2

Database 2 Table

UniqID UniqID2 Number 
100     152      2
100     153      3
```

I am trying to merge Table2 into Table1 and I'm joining on `Table1.UniqID = Table2.UniqID`. I don't want any overlapping values in the Number column, this is what I want the result to look like:

```
Table 1 

UniqID UniqID2 Number 
100     150     1
100     151     2
100     152     3
100     153     4
```

This is the query I have so far, but it only updates the row in Table 2 where the Number = 2 and doesn't increment the Number = 3 row. How can I adjust my query to do so?

```
UPDATE db2
Set db2.Number = db2.Number + 
(SELECT MAX(Number) FROM [Database 1]..db1 WHERE UniqID = db2.UniqID)
FROM [Database 2]..table db2
INNER JOIN [Database 1]..Table db1
ON db1.UniqID = db2.UniqID 
AND db1.Number = db2.Number
```

And this is what my Database 2 Table results look like right now:

```
 Database 2 Table

    UniqID UniqID2 Number 
    100     152      3
    100     153      3
```

Basically, the only difference is that I want the Number = 3 to be Number = 4 in the second column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `union all` query and `insert`:

```
insert into table1(UniqID, UniqID2, Number)
    select t2.UniqID, t2.UniqID2,
           (x.maxn + row_number() over (order by (select null) ))
    from table2 t2 cross join
         (select max(number) as maxn from table1) x;
```

Comment: After filling in the over() clause, this worked. Thank you

Comment: @cjw . . . That was an incorrect omission.  I added the `order by` clause.  You might want to order by some specific column.

Answer (score 0):

A different appraoch could be

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Number = t1.T1Number + 1
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN (SELECT uniqid, uniqid2, number as T1Number from Table1 
union 
SELECT uniqid, uniqid2, number as T1Number from Table2
) t1
ON t1.uniqid = t2.uniqid and t1.UniqID2 = t2.UniqID2-1
```

Answer (score 0):

one more approach which works in SQL 2012..

[Demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519781)

```
;With cte
as
(select * 
from 
#t
union all
select * 
from #t1
)
select uniqid,uniqid2,
 case when  lag(number) over (order by uniqid,uniqid2)  is null  then number
 when lead(number) over (order by uniqid,uniqid2) is null 
 then number+1 else  lead(number) over (order by uniqid,uniqid2)  end as nextnumber
 from cte
```